# Parse complex formula string with nested parenthesis in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, formula

I am looking for a way to parse complex VFP calculations strings.

An example of one of these formulas would be :

```
ABS((ABS(-48) - ABS(245 + 34 - 98))) + ABS(ABS(10 + 9)) > 100
```

As you can see, I have already substituted all variable patterns with there respective values - my issue is in parsing out the ABS() calls so I can substitute them out with C# Math.Abs().

In my case, I want to receive a list of string:

- ABS(-48)
- ABS(245 + 34 -98)
- ABS(10 + 9)

I thought using regex pattern matching would be the ticket, but I cannot figure out how to define a pattern that would give me (with 100% accuracy) something like "ABS(245 + 34 -98)" out of the original formula.

I would love to either know the pattern I need to use, or see someone else's example of parsing something like this successfully (I have tried many SO solutions that never parse it correctly....), or even better a suggested library that can **evaluate** (returns true or false) that calculation in as it is (I thought I had it with Datatable.Compute() - but it returns ABS(*x*) as null....).

Also, so everyone does not comment about it, I did not write these calculations...I am only trying to parse them out in C# wihtout having to change the string formulas that already exist.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use an existing library eg. https://github.com/search?q=math+formula+language%3AC%23&type=repositories

Comment: Write a parser. Evaluating a math expression has been solved many many times before. As it stands, this question is a "please write the code" type of question.

Comment: I guess the keyboard warriors have infiltrated SO 100% at this point...

I literally explained the situation, explained I have tried many SO solutions and libraries, and  simply asked how I can get the list of strings I wanted from the formula string. Any help, a good regex or other solution would have sufficed - but instead lets fill this up with negative comments based on browsing a question and not giving it any real thought - NICE!

Comment: overreaction. NICE!

Comment: To be honest, to get a robust solution, Regex will not help you. There simply is no single, short answer to your question, involving some kind of "simple" string / regex parsing. You will have to write a tokenizer and parser to get a good result. To present a solution for this is a little much to  do, without an existing attempt to built upon. Other than that, an existing library (even giving that you already tried, sorry) is your best bet.

Comment: Multiple problems: "I have tried many things and many SO solutions" – but never explain what exactly was tried (no links, no code, no [mre]) or why the existing solutions do not work for the problem at hand. Secondly, asking for a library is off-topic: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"

Comment: Since we are giving recommendations for tools: Antlr4. Buy the book, it's probably an example in the first chapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match *inmost* calls only (not a proper abstract syntax tree):

> I want to receive a list of string:
>
> - ABS(-48)
> - ABS(245 + 34 -98)
> - ABS(10 + 9)

you can try *regular expression* with a [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/KcjvQ2/1) like this:

```
[A-Za-z]+\s*\([0-9\+\*\-\s]+\)
```

C# code will be

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

...

string text = "ABS((ABS(-48) - ABS(245 + 34 - 98))) + ABS(ABS(10 + 9)) > 100";

List<string> result = Regex
  .Matches(text, @"[A-Za-z]+\s*\([0-9\/\+\/\*\-\s]+\)")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output:

```
ABS(-48)
ABS(245 + 34 - 98)
ABS(10 + 9)
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qA81w5)

Comment: This is exactly what I was originally going for, this is the pattern I could not figure out!

I can take care of the rest from here and finish this parser now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no trick to this and explaining how to do it is out of the scope of a stackoverflow question. It's a complex task and you'll just need to work through it.

A far simpler approach would be to use an existing tool such as my [SoftCircuits.ExpressionEvaluator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SoftCircuits.ExpressionEvaluator).

This library supports all the expressions in your question except the boolean operations. It's also open source, so you can review exactly how it parses it.

[SoftCircuits.Silk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SoftCircuits.Silk) is another one of my libraries. This implements an interpreted programming language and fully supports boolean expressions. Obviously, this library is more complex. But, again, it's all open source if you want to review how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are chill with recommending tools (for what ever reason).

I have been using NCalc for ages now. https://github.com/ncalc/ncalc

Though, I would recommend looking for a new and activly mainted library eg. support for the latest .net type as `System.Int128` would be nice.

There for searching on github seems your best bet
https://github.com/search?q=math+formula+language%3AC%23&type=repositories

and as was already mentioned, Regular expression isn't the right tool for the job.

Here a running demo:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0vPKkd

Notice:

I needed to change `ABS` to `Abs`, I would assume you can specify to ignore-case, but I am sure a big boy like you will figure it out.